# How you do simplify this Kotlin Getter and Settle code?

Tags: android, kotlin

**I am new to Kotlin and have been developing with the language. From Java, I am used to coding getters and setters by creating two functions. For example:**

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

**However, can this code be simplified in Kotlin? My code right now is:**

```
class ClassName{

    private var username: String? = null
    private var photoFileName: String? = null
    private var userId: String? = null
    private var requestSent: Boolean? = null

    fun ClassName(username: String?, photoFileName: String?, userId: String?, requestSent: Boolean?) {
        this.username = username
        this.photoFileName = photoFileName
        this.userId = userId
        this.requestSent = requestSent
    }

    fun getUsername(): String? {
        return username
    }
    fun setUsername(string: String){
        username = string
    }

    fun getPhotoFileName(): String? {
        return photoFileName
    }
    fun setPhotoFileName(string: String){
        photoFileName = string
    }

    fun getUserId(): String? {
        return userId
    }
    fun setUserId(string: String){
        userId = string
    }

    fun getRequestSent(): Boolean? {
        return requestSent
    }
    fun setRequestSent(bool: Boolean){
        requestSent = bool
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: Just install a plugin in android studio Android To Kotlin Class it's generate model class automatically.

Comment: There's no need to define getter/setters, they are autogenerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class will get converted to this if you use data class in kotlin. All the setters and getters will be replaced by the properties.And yes you can always call them like you used to do like set and get.

```
data class ClassName(
    var username: String,
    var photoFileName: String,
    var userId: String,
    var requestSent: String
)
```

Comment: This only has getters, not setters.

Comment: making them var will make it setters as well updated the answer

Comment: choose wisely between the val and var, var will make it mutable property.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more enhanced version of your kotlin class

```kotlin
data class YourClass(
    var username: String? = null,
    var photoFilename: String? = null,
    var userId: String? = null,
    var requestSent: Boolean? = null
)
```

You don't have to manually create setter, getter function in Kotlin.

Comment: Kotlin is a joy to work with after Java nightmare